# Illegal BlockSizeException appears only in a specific device

Tags: android, memory, encryption, memory-management

I am trying to make a simple encryption function for my android application. I am trying to encrypt a large byte array as shown below. Now although the code run perfectly on my emulator and my device, when I try to use another device it crashes producing this exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException

please note that the emulator has less ram than the device that the app crashes. Also said device allows a heap of 256mb of ram per application, while the mobile that successfully runs it allows less:

```
 byte[] b = new byte[40000];
 new Random().nextBytes(b);

 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

 byte[] first = cipher.doFinal(b);
```

the code crashes in the last line producing this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1472)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5743)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
      at eu.recred.ccs.cryptographic_credentials_storage.MainActivity.encrypt(MainActivity.java:106)
      at eu.recred.ccs.cryptographic_credentials_storage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2508)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1472) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5743) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you showed the exact code that produces the error? The exception indicates that a number of bytes was encrypted that is not a multiple of 16 (which 40000 certainly is).

Comment: Yes I am sure. Also as I said before, the code runs perfectly in other devices and emulators too, except that alcatel device, which is weird, since it has 2Gb of ram. Also if the byte[] is reduced to 15000 elements, it works...